# How can I restructure a JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to extract and restructure data from a JSON array.
I have an array of objects like this

```js
const data =
    [
      {
        "name": "EVENTNAME 1",
        "venue": "VENUE 1",
        "starttime": "09:00",
        "endtime": "12:00",
        slug: {
                 "_type" : "slug"
                 "current": "SLUG-1"
              },
       "comments": "COMMENT 1"
      },

      {
        "name": "EVENTNAME 2",
        "venue": "VENUE 2",
        "starttime": "07:00",
        "endtime": "13:00",
        slug: {
                 "_type" : "slug"
                 "current": "SLUG-2"
              },
       "comments": "COMMENT 2"
      },

      {
        "name": "EVENTNAME 3",
        "venue": "VENUE 3",
        "starttime": "10:00",
        "endtime": "12:00",
        slug: {
                 "_type" : "slug"
                 "current": "SLUG-3"
              },
       "comments": "COMMENT 3"
      }
  ]
```

But I would like to restructure it into a different format, something like this for example:

```js
    [
      {
        "Name": "EVENTNAME 1",
        "Location": "VENUE 1",
        "Time": "09:00",
        Slug:"SLUG-1"
            
      },

      {
        "Name": "EVENTNAME 2",
        "Location": "VENUE 2",
        "Time": "07:00",
        Slug:"SLUG-3"
      },

      {
        "Name": "EVENTNAME 3",
        "Location": "VENUE 3",
        "Time": "10:00",
        Slug:"SLUG-3"
      }
  ]
```

I have the following code which mostly works:

```js
const newarray = data.map((item) => {
    

    return {
      
      Name: item.name,
      Location: item.venue,
      Time: item.starttime,
      Slug: item.slug.current

    };
  });
```

However I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')

If I leave out the Slug... part it works fine.

Is there something missing, because if I log out the original data array, it shows that `slug.current` is defined.

Stack Snippet:

```js
const data =
    [
      {
        "name": "EVENTNAME 1",
        "venue": "VENUE 1",
        "starttime": "09:00",
        "endtime": "12:00",
        slug: {
                 "_type" : "slug",
                 "current": "SLUG-1"
              },
       "comments": "COMMENT 1"
      },

      {
        "name": "EVENTNAME 2",
        "venue": "VENUE 2",
        "starttime": "07:00",
        "endtime": "13:00",
        slug: {
                 "_type" : "slug",
                 "current": "SLUG-2"
              },
       "comments": "COMMENT 2"
      },

      {
        "name": "EVENTNAME 3",
        "venue": "VENUE 3",
        "starttime": "10:00",
        "endtime": "12:00",
        slug: {
                 "_type" : "slug",
                 "current": "SLUG-3"
              },
       "comments": "COMMENT 3"
      }
  ]
        
/* Wanted:
    [
      {
        "Name": "EVENTNAME 1",
        "Location": "VENUE 1",
        "Time": "09:00",
        Slug:"SLUG-1"
            
      },

      {
        "Name": "EVENTNAME 2",
        "Location": "VENUE 2",
        "Time": "07:00",
        Slug:"SLUG-3"
      },

      {
        "Name": "EVENTNAME 3",
        "Location": "VENUE 3",
        "Time": "10:00",
        Slug:"SLUG-3"
      }
  ]
*/

const newarray = data.map((item) => {
    return {
      Name: item.name,
      Location: item.venue,
      Time: item.starttime,
      Slug: item.slug.current
    };
  });
console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Seems to be working fine with the data you've posted here. Probably when dealing with real data, some items are missing slug field?

Comment: The error means you have an item without `slug` property. Check your input. This should be easy to debug.

Comment: *"However I get this error:"* If I fix the typos in the code (missing `,`, mostly), it runs just fine with what you've provided. **If** you have elements that don't have a `slug` property, then of course that would cause the error you describe. So you have to handle that, perhaps with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 1):

It seems very likely that one of your items doesn't have a `slug` on it.

Try this to debug:

```js
data.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (!item.slug) {
    console.log(index, item);
  }
});
```

It will log all of the items in your original array that don't have `slug` (and `index` tells you where they are in the array)